# How to show more than 1000 records in Algolia instantsearch.js

Tags: algolia

I'm using Algolia along with instantsearch.js in a project to make searches and show categories and contents inside them (category page and search pages are powered by Algolia). We are using instantsearch.js v1 is from cdn.

Our main issue is that search doesn't provide more than 1000 records which we need.

As far as I understand correctly, `browse()` method provides more results, but it's not usable in instantsearch.js.

Also, after reading docs, I found out that there's a new option called `paginationLimitedTo`, which allows displaying more than 1000 records:

https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest-api/search/#paginationlimitedto

So, setting this would allow displaying more than 1000 records.

Can you help me here, how should I achieve getting more than 1000 records, or if it'd achieve our goal, how do we set this `paginationLimitedTo` attribute in instantsearch.js ? I'm okay if I need to build or edit instantsearch.js for the time being.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change the value for `paginationLimitedTo`, you will need to create a custom `client` object, then get your `index` by doing calling `client.initIndex(indexName)`, and then change the setting by calling

```
index.setSettings({
  paginationLimitedTo: 1000
});
```

You can check the guide for that in the docs [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/instant-search/#index-configuration-using-the-api).

Also, please remember the following:

> We recommend keeping the default value to guarantee excellent performance. Increasing the pagination limit will have a direct impact on the performance of search queries. A too high value will also make it very easy for anyone to retrieve (“scrape”) your entire dataset.

Comment: to add to that, you can use `options.createAlgoliaClient` https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#initialization for adding the custom client

Comment: @HaroenViaene & Guy :  Hello, thanks for the fast responses! however, when I set like this, public api key throws me saying "Method not allowed with this API key", but when I use my admin key it works! And surely I won't be using my admin key in public Javascript file. Any other workarounds ? Here's the gist of what I tried: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d1171aa046a52e011d466e38c6b17aa4

Comment: `paginationLimitedTo` setting cannot be set on query time, it can be set once via `setSettings` method with admin API key. So you need to set it just once and not with every query.

Comment: Hey, I just asked this to someone else again, and you can set this parameter without a custom client too, with `searchParameters`, just the same way. Check out https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/searching/why-is-search-limited-to-1000-results/#faq-section too but I really advice you to not to it :)

Comment: @JanPetr I was only setting it once with the Admin was I have created a custom API key which allows search and browse. That was the thing I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: @HaroenViaene Thank you, actually the search pages are also category pages on my project, because instantsearch.js already covers everything regarding a category page for my case, thus I need to show every result within pagination. As your link suggested, I have created a custom ACL with search and browse, which solved my issue. Thank you!

Comment: Does the recommendation to keep it under 1000 suggest that Algolia is not a good candidate for apps that want to give users the ability to query for and browse through sets with thousands of hits?

Comment: Also, when you do it this way, don't count on nbPages being accurate.  It will still say 100 pages (if you have hitsPerPage set to 10), but you'll be able to request pages past 100 and it will return them without error.